# Madvertise on Load

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey Guys i got this code in my Activity:

```
public class MYAppActivity extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private MadvertiseView mMadView;
 private AdView mAdmView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    mAdmView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.admad);
    mMadView = (MadvertiseView)findViewById(R.id.madad);


}

     @Override
     public void onLoaded(boolean succeed, MadvertiseView  mMadView) {
     if (succeed) {
     // ad loaded, set view visible
     Log.d("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Ad successfully loaded");
     mMadView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else {
     // ad could not be loaded, set view to invisible
     Log.w("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Ad could not be loaded");
     mMadView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
     }
```

and i get this error:The method onLoaded(boolean, MadvertiseView) of type MYAppActivity must override or implement a supertype methodUniversal/src/de/ollidiemaus/MYApp line 58 Java Problem

Any of you guys know whats wrong with my app?
I used the latest madvertise sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line: 
    super.onLoaded(succeed,mMadView) 
before if statement.May be it can help. Your code will look something like this:

```
 public void onLoaded(boolean succeed, MadvertiseView  mMadView) {
 if (succeed) {
 // ad loaded, set view visible
 Log.d("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Ad successfully loaded");
 mMadView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 } else {
 // ad could not be loaded, set view to invisible
 Log.w("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Ad could not be loaded");
 mMadView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
 }
```

Comment: by using: "public void super.onLoaded(boolean succeed, MadvertiseView  mMadView) {"
I'll get this two errors:
Return type for the method is missing
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

So i think this isn't the right solution xD

Comment: No you have taken it wrongly.Correct way of doing it is shown in my answer.See my edited answer.

Comment: okay then I'll get a new error xDD :


The method onLoaded(boolean, MadvertiseView) is undefined for the type Activity

Comment: Remove annotations from your original code(before adding the statement told by me) and then tell me what it is showing.

Comment: @Override
      public void onLoaded(boolean succeed, MadvertiseView mMadView) {
       super.onLoaded(succeed,mMadView);
      if (succeed) {
      Log.d("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Ad successfully loaded");
      mMadView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
      Log.w("YOUR_LOG_TAG", "Ad could not be loaded");
      mMadView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
      }

The error is:

Comment: You are not getting me.I'm telling you to remove annotations (@Override) from the code which you pasted in your question and then compile it and tell me what error is it showing ?

Comment: okay by deleting the @Override and without your added line everthing worked fine

Comment: In future if you get this type of errors then there are only a few possiblities just as in your case removing override annotations.Anyways glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you override onloaded when you have not made your activity implement the specific adview interface, nor set the listener to `this`. How does your adview now how to call the method??